# How to display at most N decimals and no decimals if not needed in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, string, format

say I have these 3 floats:

```
10,
10.12
10.234
```

And I want to print at most 1 decimal, but no decimals if not needed, like this:

```
10
10.1
10.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `"#.#"` format in `ToString`. Use it like:

```
decimal d = 10M;
string str = d.ToString("#.#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Consider the following example:

```
List<float> list = new List<float> { 10f, 10.12f, 10.234f };
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", item, item.ToString("#.#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

and you will get:

```
10 => 10
10.12 => 10.1
10.234 => 10.2
```

See: [Custom Numeric Format Strings - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For the comment:

> With the provided example works fine, However when used on 0.2 it
>   returns .2. Is this the only way? –

Use: `"0.#`,

If you look at the above specified [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then for `0` you will find:

> Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present;
>   otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

Comment: With the provided example works fine, However when used on `0.2` it returns `.2`. Is this the only way?

Comment: @pepOS, in that case use `0.#`,

Comment: I confirm it also works like this: string.Format("{0:#.#}", 1.12f)